# Server freeze Tomcat Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, couchdb

I have two project deployed on Ubuntu server. 
One is a web application and other is central project which is called from different users. This web app also call this central project. Other users are mobile apps, other servers.

I have used couch-db for database.

The problem is after some time the Web app is not able to communicate with this central project. It just hangs. And there is no logs entries.
I don't know weather the number of file descriptors increases or the couchdb is creating problem or it is exceeding the limit for couchdb connections.

But when the mobile app is calling the central server, I can see it is working fine.

Please help me.

Comment: need more details. we can all guess at the web server / app server config, but why don't you tell us what is running. Also since you must be using Apache???? there are most likely access log entries for your failed connections.

Comment: My server is tomcat. When the web app tries to communicate with this central server which is performing all the operation including couchdb operation, it just freezes. But the mobile app can call any webservices of this central server.